# Computing absolute difference between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and I was wondering if there was a way I could run formulas on two dataframes.

I have two dfs that have the same columns and same index. example each df looks like this

`x y z
a  2 4 5
b  7 9 0`

I want to take df1, df2 and find the absolute difference for x ,y, z something like (df1[n]-df2[n] / df1[n]) * 100 for each n element of columns, and store the result in a new df.

Note: I just want the difference to be positive. (Misunderstood the meaning of absolute)

Answer (score 1):

Yes run them as you wrote them

absolute

`(df1 - df2).abs()`

or

`(df1 -df2).div(df2) * 100`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the formula you provided (`(df1[n]-df2[n] / df1[n]) * 100`), you will get different results. You can use the Pandas `abs` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs

Some examples:

```python
a = {'x': [2], 'y': [4], 'z': [5]}
b = {'x': [7], 'y': [9], 'z': [0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

df_abs = abs(df1 - df2)  # Absolute difference
df_abs = (df1 - df2 / df1) * 100  # Different results
```

Comment: Another use of the abs method is provided by @Kenan: `(df1 - df2).abs()`

Comment: I would suggest update link. You are using `abs(df1 - df2)` in answer which is `python built-in function abs` but you gave link of `pandas.DataFrame.abs` in description. and when you use `(df1 - df2).abs()` then actually you are using `pandas.DataFrame.abs` function.